# Rails app on Apache and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a Rails 3.0.7 app that is working fine in a development mode on a Windows 7 box under Webrick.

I started to move it to a production host based on ESX 4.2, CentOS 6.2, Apache 2.2.15, Ruby 1.9.3p125, Rails 3.2.3 and passenger 3.0.11 and mysql 14.14. The various installs appeared to have ran clean. The bundle install was clean and I ran `bundle exec rake db:migrate` which also ran clean.

I am new to the Apache/passenger/rails environment and may not understand how to configure all this correctly. I have read many posts on the issue and followed those ideas making some progress but I'm still having an error. As I understand it, if you add the `vituralhost` block to the Apache config file it should start `passenger` and that finds the rails app and life should be happy, but it's not.

In the `VituralHost` block I do have public at the end of the path for both `DocumentRoot` and `Directory`; the options include:

Allow from all
 AllowOverride all
 Options -MultiViews

From firefox on a Win7 host I enter `172.16.2.226` and get:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
These are the possible causes:

    There may be a syntax error in the application's code. Please check for such errors and fix them.
    A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
    The application may not be properly configured. Please check whether all configuration files are written correctly, fix any incorrect configurations, and restart this application.
    A service that the application relies on (such as the database server or the Ferret search engine server) may not have been started. Please start that service.

Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
   git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
Application root:
    /var/www/html/Scarfs
```

I do have gem line for `linecache19`, `ruby-debug-base19` and `ruby-debug19` in the Gemfile.  I got a feeling that the varous verions don't play well together? I'm concerned about the linecache error and specifing `linechace19` in the Gemfile?  But I needed the `linecache19` to solve a different problem.

I have also tried stopping the `httpd` service and run `passenger` in standalone mode with:

```
passenger start -a 172.16.2.226 -p 80 -d -e development
```

I get the same "passenger could not be started" error.

If I change the port to 3000 I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error in Firefox.

Anyone got ideas where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You do know it should be "VirtualHost", yes?

Comment: THe coded value is correct, just a fat finger on he question.